# pyinstaller mkdir function won't work after creating executable

Tags: python, mkdir, permission-denied, pyinstaller

Python 2.7

Ubuntu 12.04

I'm trying to create an executable of a program I have written, the first thing it needs to do is create a directory, when running the source code it works perfectly, when I create an executable I get the following error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/"folder_name"'
```

The code for creating the folder:

```
def create_folder(self, user_input):
    """create base folder"""
    splitput = user_input.split('=')      
    fold_title = splitput[-1]
    try:
        print 'making folder'
        os.mkdir('/'+fold_title, 0777)
        print 'made folder'
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        print 'failed to create folder'
        returned_path = '/'+fold_title+'/'

    returned_path = '/'+fold_title+'/'
    print returned_path
    return returned_path
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current user has no privilege to create a directory under "/". And there are qoutation marks in varible "fold_title", check it out if you really need qoutation marks in the path.

Comment: I'm having this issue too but I'm the admin on the machine so I don't know how privileges could be affecting it. If they are despite my admin account, how do I go about dealing with this then?